# python html escaping utf-8 from commandline

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cgi, url-encoding

I wrote a simple support script which converts strings from stdin to a htmlencoded version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import fileinput


for line in fileinput.input():
    print cgi.escape(line).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

This down exactly what i need:

```
$ echo "AA<>BB"|htmlescape
AA&lt;&gt;BB
```

However when the input contains a few simple non ascii characters the tool crashes:

```
$ echo "AA<>BBeëCC"|htmlescape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/remco/bin/htmlescape", line 7, in <module>
    print cgi.escape(line).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

what can i do to make the script accept non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to encode bytestrings:

```
>>> 'AA<>BBeëCC'.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python is trying to be helpful, you can only encode a Unicode string to bytes, so to encode Python first implicitly *decodes*, using the default codec ASCII.

You'll have to *explicitly* decode first, using a suitable codec. Because you are using a pipe, Python cannot detect the input codec. You'll have to explicitly set one, either in Python itself, as a command line option or using a environment variable.

Lets assume your console has been configured to use UTF-8, then you can use:

```
print cgi.escape(line.decode('utf8')).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Demo:

```
>>> 'AA<>BBeëCC'.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'AA<>BBe&#235;CC'
```

You could use the [`locale.getpreferredencoding()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) to introspect the terminal codec configuration:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import fileinput
import locale


codec = locale.getpreferredencoding()


for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.decode(codec)
    print cgi.escape(line).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

That way you always match whatever codec the terminal was using to accept input, and you can also set the codec using an environment variable:

```
LC_CTYPE='en_US.ISO-8859-1 echo "latin text" | htmlescape
```

to tell Python to decode using the Latin-1 codec.

Comment: This seem to work great thank. One thine when i put the text in a fit and cat it to the script i still get the same error.

Comment: @user3181422: what codec did you use for the file then?